# Regex to validate a twitter url

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using the jQuery validation engine to parse my form data:
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

What would be the regex to validate a twitter URL (including the http://twitter.com part) Eg:

```
http://twitter.com/barackobama
or
http://twitter.com/#!/barackobama
```

Comment: maybe it's easier to do without regex in this case??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You mean

```
/http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www\.)?twitter\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/
```

Comment: I was wondering: aren't twitter users allowed to use non [a-zA-Z] letters in their names? It seem rather unfair to all the asian/russian/arabic users...

Comment: Looks like it's past time to update this answer, Twitter stopped using the `#!` URLs on May 29, 2012 ([source](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/improving-performance-on-twittercom))  Here is a quick regex demo showing the updated RegEx working https://regex101.com/r/sH1hX1/1

Comment: There are two answers with equal votes. One is older but marked correct. Which one is MORE correct?

Comment: @JasonSperske Your URL is accepting `https://wwwtwitter.com/SND_TST` too which is incorrect. You need to add `\.` too alongwith `www` inside brackets.

Answer (score 15):

```
/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?twitter\.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[\w\-]*\/)*([\w\-]*)/
```

with optional using https or add www
e.g

```
http://twitter.com/example
https://twitter.com/example
http://www.twitter.com/example
https://www.twitter.com/example
```

is valid

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with jQuery but if it uses standard regex it would be something like this:

```
http://twitter.com/(#!/)?[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}
```

This bit `(#!/)?` is to make the #!/ optional, and this `[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}` is because Twitter usernames can contain letters (upper or lowercase), numbers and underscores and can be up to 15 characters in length.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider differences between **http** and **https** and of course **www**. Many of answer forget this rule.

```
'/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/i'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
http:\/\/twitter\.com\/(#!\/)?\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url.match(/http:\/\/twitter.com\/(#!\/)?(\w*)/i);
```